# Select2 plugin fired by

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

newbie here
first, my english is not good enough to describe the problem that i'm facing right now, so consider to see my code below

```
$('#selectOriginAirport, #selectDestinationAirport').select2({
            placeholder: 'Select Airport',
            ajax: {
                url: '{{url('get-airports')}}',
                dataType: 'json',
                delay: 250,
                data: function(params){
                    return { keyword: params.term };
                },
                processResults: function(datas, params) {
                    return {
                        results: $.map(datas.data, function(item) {
                            return {
                                text: item.cityName + ' - '+item.airportName + ' ('+item.airportCode+')',
                                id: item.airportCode+'|'+item.cityName,
                                lat: item.airportLatitude,
                                lon: item.airportLongitude
                            }
                        })
                    };
                },
                cache: true
            },
            escapeMarkup: function (markup) { 
                // console.log('markup >>> ' + markup);
                return markup; 
            },
            minimumInputLength: 3,
            templateResult: function(data) {
                // console.log('data >>> ' + data);
                if(data.loading) {
                    return data.text;
                }
                var markup = '<p>'+data.text+'</p>';
                return markup;
            },
            templateSelection: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                if($(this).is('#selectOriginAirport')){
                    console.log('pepaya');
                    $("[name='flightOriginLat']").val(data.lat);
                    $("[name='flightOriginLon']").val(data.lon);
                }
                if($(this).is('#selectDestinationAirport')){
                    console.log('kates');
                    $("[name='flightDestinationLat']").val(data.lat);
                    $("[name='flightDestinationLon']").val(data.lon);
                // }
                return data.airportName || data.text;
            }
        });
```

first take a look that i fire select2 by #selectOriginAirport and selectDestinationAirport

the problem is i need to make a conditional on the templateSelection function but its not work, the result is none of that 2 logical is executed

thats the problem i need to solve i wish you get what i mean
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I checked the source code for select2 and it looks like select2 **does** pass the container as the second parameter in the `templateSelection` option. Here's the relevant snippet from the select2.js

```
SingleSelection.prototype.display = function (data, container) {
  var template = this.options.get('templateSelection');
  var escapeMarkup = this.options.get('escapeMarkup');

  return escapeMarkup(template(data, container));
};
```

Using that and JSFiddle's `/echo/json` as a sample AJAX, I've created a working snippet:
http://jsfiddle.net/shashank2104/ozy16L8s/2/

**Relevant code:**

```
templateSelection: function(selection,inst) {
   if(inst && inst.length) {
       return inst.attr('id') === 'select2-user-email-address-container' ? selection.email : selection.id;
   }
}
```

Based on the container ID, the appropriate attribute can be chosen. Hope this helps.